# (Adobe Acrobat CC) if statement in calculation not working

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, acrobat, calculation

I'm trying to make a PDF form out of a D&D Character Sheet. I'm blindly stumbling my way around javascript so sorry if I n00b out.

I've got a text field called Acro Mod next to a checkbox (named Acro Pro). I want this text field to equal the sum of two other text fields (DEX MOD + Proficiency) if the box is checked, and equal only one (DEX MOD) if it isn't checked. I've managed to kludge together what I could of the javascript to do that, but it will only ever return one of the values regardless of checkbox status. Here's what the code in the calculation box for the Acro Mod text field looks like:

```
var acropro =  this.getField("Acro Pro").value;
var dexmod =  this.getField("DEX MOD").value;
var prof = this.getField("Proficiency").value;
if (acropro != "off"){
event.value = dexmod + prof;
} else { 
event.value = dexmod;
}
```

Basically what I want is: if checkbox = off then textA = textB, if checkbox=on then textA = textB + textC

I get the sense that I've screwed up the grammar somewhere in the code but I can't seem to figure out how or where. Can somebody who knows what they're doing tell me why this isn't working?

Answer (score 2):

The unchecked value of a checkbox or radio button is "Off"... capital O

```
if (acropro != "Off"){
```

Comment: Crap, thanks. That's exactly what I was screwing up. I knew it was something like that.